# Jquery access attributes where the data attribute is substring

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

Thanks a million for taking the time to read this :) First let me show you the example code I am dealing with:

```
<div id="section-0000001" class="section" data-section-223344="{"id":"123456", "type":"product"}">
  <div>Section 0000001</div>
</div>
<div id="section-0000002" class="section" data-section-223344="{"id":"123456", "type":"category"}">
  <div>Section 0000002</div>
</div>
<div id="section-123456" class="section" data-section-223344="{"id":"123456", "type":"showcase-product"}">
  <div>Section 123456</div>
</div>
<div id="section-234567" class="section" data-section-223344="{"id":"234567", "type":"showcase-product"}">
  <div>Section 234567</div>
</div>
<div id="section-345678" class="section" data-section-223344="{"id":"345678", "type":"showcase-product"}">
  <div>Section 345678</div>
</div>
<div id="section-0000003" class="section" data-section-223344="{"id":"123456", "type":"image"}">
  <div>Section 0000003</div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve, is to add a class to all divs with the type 'showcase-product'. I do not have access to the original code so I need to do this with Jquery. There is unfortunately not a unique class to filter these out and the only thing unique is the showcase-product but as you can see that is part of an object within the data attribute and I cannot figure out how to access it.

If the attribute data-section-xxxxxx was the same, this would be much easier but each div has a unique value on the end but the first part data-section- is always the same.

I can loop through the divs with this:

```
$('.section').each(function(){
    for(data in $(this).data())
        console.log(data); 
});
```

But I cannot figure out a way to filter out only the divs with type = showcase-product.

I also tried a different approach:

```
$( ".section" ).each(function( i ) {
    element=this;
    $.each(this.attributes, function() {
       if(this.name.indexOf('data-section') != -1) 
           $(element).addClass("myClass");
    });
});
```

This adds the class but it also adds it to the ones without type = showcase-product such as type = image or type = category.

I guess it might be something like

```
this.name.type.value.indeOf('data-section') != 1
```

But I am not sure of the correct syntax or how to access it especially since type is not the value, it's an object within the value.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this approach; what it does is explained in the comments:

```js
$(".section").each(function(i, element) {
  // get dataset values
  var dataValues = Object.values(element.dataset);
  // find if has type using a regular expression
  var foundType = false;
  for (var j = 0; j < dataValues.length; j++) {
    if (dataValues[j].match(/\"type\":\"showcase-product\"/)) {
      foundType = true; // one dataset value matched!
    }
  }
  // skip this element if no match
  if (!foundType) return;
  // do your stuff with showcase-product here:
  console.log(element, 'found!');
  $(element).addClass("myClass");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section-0000001" class="section" data-section-223344='{"id":"123456", "type":"product"}'>
<div>Section 0000001</div>
</div>
<div id="section-0000002" class="section" data-section-223344='{"id":"123456", "type":"category"}'>
<div>Section 0000002</div>
</div>
<div id="section-123456" class="section" data-section-223344='{"id":"123456", "type":"showcase-product"}'>
<div>Section 123456</div>
</div>
```